# How change width for edit window

Tags: 2sxc

I have a content type with some fields, but the width for edit window is not enought.

Is there any option to change the width for edit window. I noticed style have max-width:800px!important value, but it should be nice to have an option to change the size for the window.

Comment: As of now there is no such feature. Can you maybe explain why this would be important? The UI is responsive, and normally such wide dialogs would be very hard to work with.

Comment: I have custom blog module, based on your blog app, but this have a lot of fields, and the wysiwyg im using is custom too, with much more buttons and plugins so in my case i need more horizontal space for edition, maybe is a very specific need, but I was thinking maybe was possible with no effort. For now i changed the css adjusting to my needs, so if I update the module i need to make the change again. Thanks anyway, and seriously, thanks for your effort, your module helped me to accomplish some very complex scenarios.

Comment: Your welcome - and thanks for the feedback.